# Google Script in Google Sheet - Make copy of sheet loses permissions

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a google sheet that has a script embedded.

In the script > resources > cloud platform project, I have added and linked a project to this script to enable the APIs. This works great in the current Google Sheet.

[image]

**Challenge:**

When I make a copy of the Google Sheet the Cloud Platform assigned project is lost and it requires users to enable these permissions again.

Is there a way to prevent this from happening? Am I missing a setting?

Comment: I guess it's because you're just copying the file and not the whole system coming with. I'm not sure it's either possible to do what you're looking for.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you first link a [Standard Cloud Platform project](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/cloud-platform-projects#standard_cloud_platform_projects) to your GAS project. Then you make a copy the spreadsheet to which your Script is bound, and you want the copied Script to keep the 'link' to the Cloud Platform project. Is that the situation?

Comment: @lamblichus - yes exactly that. The google sheet loses it's bind when a copy of that sheet is made. I don't want users to be editing the original copy itself. It's more of a template to which each user grabs a new copy of.

Comment: @Justin, if the only reason you want a GCP project associated with your script is enabling APIs, can't you just activate the appropriate [Advanced Google services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced)?

Comment: @Iamblichus By adding the Standard Cloud Platform it automatically marks the appropriate Advanced Google Services required. This seems to require authentication the first time which is fine but when I copy the sheet it requires authenticating again

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying to do is not possible. Even if you try making a copy of a [standalone script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/standalone) that has a GCP project associated, you will get the same functionality (no GCP project associated).

Also, it makes sense that each new user that runs the script has to explicitly authorize the APIs to make changes in their files, send emails on their behalf, or what have you. It's a basic step in the [3-legged OAuth 2.0 workflow](https://www.google.com/support/enterprise/static/gapps/art/admin/en/cpanel/3-legged-oauth-diagram.png), and it can only avoided if you use a [Service Account](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount).

So in your situation, I would just use [Advanced Google services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced), even if each new user has to grant authorization. In the end, the appropriate advanced services are automatically enabled in your copied project; users don't need to enable them manually, only grant them authorization.

Reference:

https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2

https://support.google.com/a/answer/2538798?hl=en